# SSRS - How to build a simple multi-column report?

Tags: reporting-services

I am using SQL Server 2008 and I want to show 1 single field from a table in multiple columns in the report. Just like if I were to print labels. How can I achieve this?

Example:

Instead of printing:

### Names Report

Andrea
Austin
Barbara
Bob
Bruno
Cathy
Chis
...

I want to print in columns (say 3 fixed columns):

### Names Report

Andrea ---- Bruno ---- Darren 
Austin ---- Cathy  ---- Francis
Barbara ---- Chis  ---- Gabriel
Bob ---- David  ---- Gerald
.......  ---- .......  ---- .......

**Edit:** If I run the report and click on "Print Layout" button, I can see multiple columns. Can I set this mode as default?

Comment: You really need to post more detail about what you are trying to achieve - but why not use a table element in the report designer.

Comment: I agree. Sorry. I've updated the question adding more details.
Thanks

Comment: I only have one field (Name) begin displayed. I want to flow into multiple columns, like when you select a block of text in a text editor and format it to more than one column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the 'Report' menu in Visual Studio and select 'Report Properties'.  You can set columns in the 'Layout' tab.

Try this msdn article about *newsletter-style reports* for more details: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159107.aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms159107(v=sql.105))

This method does have a limitation though so in some cases it might not be applicable:

> Only PDF and Image renderers support
>   newsletter-style reports.

EDIT:
So one approach is to use multiple tablix with a filter that checks RowNumber and accordingly displays particular records in each table.

The other way is called **Newsletter-style report** [(link)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms159107(v=sql.105)). This formatting is retained only when  report is exported as PDF or Image. It can be previewed only when you select 'Print Layout' on the Preview tab in Visual Studio. Here is an example:

1. Create a new report with the foll. dataset: `SELECT ID,NAME FROM TABLENAME`
2. Add a new table to the report and select the ID and Name as columns
3. Click on the tablix and press F4 to edit the tablix properties. In the properties window, change the Size - set the width to 2in
4. Click on the report area outside the report page boundary and press F4 to edit the report properties. In the properties window, change the Column value to 3, and column spacing value to 0.1
5. On the report scroll to the right hand side, you will notice that there are 2 new columns (so totally 3 columns on the report - because you selected 3 in step 4 above). Now click on the margin at the start of the column 2 and pull it further to the left to bring it as close to the column 1. This is only to reduce the need for huge page size.
6. Right click on the report area outside the report page boundary and select Report Properties. Change the Page Size - Set the width to 10in
7. Preview the report. Now select the 'Print Layout' tab to see the result. This formatting is retained only when  report is exported as PDF or Image.

As noted in points 5 and 6 - since the report body flows into multiple columns, you must ensure that the page size is at-least equal to -> ([Original report body  size times the number of columns] + all the column spacing values). Otherwise it will look messy.

Comment: Bo, thanks but this really doesn't help much. Adding a column to the report doesn't automatically split the content in columns. What do I need to do to show the data in columns after adding the columns to the report?

Comment: I tested this and it worked for me.  I had to clean up the report to put the columns where I wanted, but there were automatically 3 columns on the page once I made room for everything. Perhaps I'm not exactly understanding what you need.

Comment: What did you use to display the data? What controls? In my case I have a Tablix containing a TextBox bound to the field. I still get 1 single column in the report even though, the report has 2 columns specified.

Comment: If I run the report and click on "Print Layout" button, I can see multiple columns. Can I set this mode as default?

Comment: Did you get this figured out?

Comment: The reason that this works in "Print Layout" and not during regular rendering is because this method is supported in PDF and Image only...

Answer (score 14):

For Horizontal layout of labels...

One choice is to use the columns property on the report or body elements.
This doesn't always display correctly On reportviewer. I've noticed that even if it displays correctly on your IDE and when you export to PDF. In the report viewer it will display only one column. Also it snakes the labels top to bottom then left to right.

One choice is to use a matrix and group on every 3 rows (if you want 3 columns).

This one is a little complicated.

My solution of choice is to put 3 vertical lists on the page. put the same label in each list. Return the row number in your dataset. Then just filter each list  on modulo 3

For example

Result set

```
RIndex Fname
1 abe
2 burt
3 fred
4 george
```

Filter expressions

```
list 1 -> =Fields!RIndex.Value mod 3 = =1
list 2 -> =Fields!RIndex.Value mod 3 = =2
list 3 -> =Fields!RIndex.Value mod 3 = =0
```

Result

```
Abe Burt Fred 
George
```

Comment: The modulo hack is pure genious! @Vern you're a star

Answer (score 6):

The method I use is a bit similar as what Vern suggested but differs enough to make it worth mentioning here.

You can combine the ROW_NUMBER with the modulo (%) operator directly in the query to fabricate the column number in which the record should get displayed. Here's an example that generates one while taking a group into account:

```
declare @numberOfColumns int = 4;

select dpc.EnglishProductCategoryName, dp.ProductAlternateKey
    , (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY dpc.EnglishProductCategoryName
        ORDER BY dp.ProductAlternateKey) + @numberOfColumns - 1) % @numberOfColumns + 1
    as DisplayColumn
from dbo.DimProduct dp
inner join dbo.DimProductSubcategory dps on dps.ProductSubcategoryKey = dp.ProductSubcategoryKey
inner join dbo.DimProductCategory dpc on dpc.ProductCategoryKey = dps.ProductCategoryKey;
```

To get this displayed I'm using nested tables which are then filtered on DisplayColumn.

Have a read through following article for all the details: [Creating Multiple-Column Reports](http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2012/11/01/creating-multiple-column-reports/)

Comment: Personally, I've found this to be the best solution. Using a CTE to join the data over itself and then using a % to remove the duplication. Using columns in SSRS is a nightmare.