# SSRS: Am I hallucinating?

Tags: ssrs-2008

The solution at

[SSRS - How to build a simple multi-column report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015098/ssrs-how-to-build-a-simple-multi-column-report)

says there is a layout tab under the report properties. Ive googled the subject to death and the same menu is referred to in multiple places. I can't find a Layout Tab or a Columns property anywhere. Have I gone round the bend? 
[image: ReportMenu]

[image: NoLayoutTab]

[image: NoColumnsProperty]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the Columns property, you've clicked on the **Body** of the report which brings up the body properties.  To view the Columns property, click outside the Body of the report on the yellowish area.  The Columns property will be under the "Page" group.

Alternatively, you can open the **Properties** pane and select **Report** from the dropdown list at the top of the pane to view all report properties.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Alison. You are a ninja. =)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the Layout tab was removed in VS2008 (or "bids" based on VS2008). In the previous version there were three tabs - Data, Layout and Preview.

In the 2008 version, the functionality that was available in the Data tab moved to the report data pane and Layout was renamed (and redesigned) to Design.

Still a lot of articles, posts etc. out there that refers to the Layout-tab though.

Anyway... Most properties must be available elsewhere, such as the Report properties pane etc.