# Creating a Directory Listing type Report in SSRS

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report

I was wondering if there was a way to create a directory listing report in ssrs and if so, how would i go about creating it. 
I'm mostly familiar with creating tabular and some somewhat complex reports, but nothing like this; so any help would be extremely useful.

Here's a sample of how the report might look.

[image: Sample Report]

Thanks!

**Addendum**: The content on each page needs to be grouped by Department & Sub-Department.
I made a mistake on the sample report; where it says Department Subtitle it should say sub-department.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way I've seen it done.

For a 3 column look, create 3 tables/list with the same dataset and set visibility for details group to:

```
=IIF(ROWNUMBER("YourDataSet") mod 3=1,FALSE,TRUE) <--Table1 
=IIF(ROWNUMBER("YourDataSet") mod 3=2,FALSE,TRUE) <--Table2
=IIF(ROWNUMBER("YourDataSet") mod 3=0,FALSE,TRUE) <--Table3
```

Comment: I'm sorry i should have clarified my question a bit more. I added some additional info to the original question. This addition might not allow me to use this method. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is an addition to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015098/ssrs-how-to-build-a-simple-multi-column-report).

I did a simple test that imitates your situation. Here is how to do it:

1. Set the report to **3 columns** via Report properties. Adjusted the width of each column so that they fit in 1 page of paper.
2. Add a **List control** to the first column. Put Text Box controls inside with the required data fields. The List control will repeat for each Listing record.
3. Create **groups** for Department and Sub-Department via Row Groups pane. Rearrange the groups so that they will appear above the List control.
4. Right-click on Department group (or Sub-Department group) and add **Page Breaks**.
5. Preview (Should get a result pretty close to what you want)