# Displaying dataset in 4 column layout

Tags: reporting-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SSRS - How to build a simple multi-column report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015098/ssrs-how-to-build-a-simple-multi-column-report)

I have a report made in SSRS, that looks like this:

```
January
#data11
#data12
...

.
.
.

December
#data121
#data122
...
```

Is there a way to layout the report like this:

```
January   February    March     April
data..    data...     data...   data...

May       June        July      August
data...   data...     Data..    data..
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion:

- Take 3 matrix tables
- place one below the other
- group column by month to all three matrix tables

Add filters (filter tab in group properties) in group properties as below for each table:

- Matrix Table 1: `month <=4`
- Matrix Table 2: `month >4 and month<=8`
- Matrix Table 3: `month >8 and month<=12`