# SSRS multi column list report how to create from one dataset

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

Hello I have a report which has multiple sections.

For each section I need the data to be displayed in a 2 column list. 
So instead of the report having just one column and waste space on right, I require it to populate on the other column. I am currently using a list to populate the field from dataset I require however just get one long list.

See attachment for what I'm looking to achieve.[image: xample]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSRS - How to build a simple multi-column report?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015098/ssrs-how-to-build-a-simple-multi-column-report)

Comment: Had a look at that before and didn't really solve

Comment: Then explain what you have tried and why those solutions didn't work.

Comment: I have static text boxes which I only want visible on top of first column. Is there a way to have text box only to be displayed once ?

Comment: Are you using the modula method to display things in one column or the other?  Then you should be able to use the Hidden with an expression to show or hide based on that as well

Comment: https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/12331/Simple-way-to-show-multi-column-data-in-SSRS-Horizontally-or-Vertically.html solved with this link

Answer (score 0):

https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/12331/Simple-way-to-show-multi-column-data-in-SSRS-Horizontally-or-Vertically.html

this link explains well how to achieve this