# SSRS 2019 Can I limit the number of rows in a table and then move up to the top to show remaining rows for dataset?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I am in  the Healthcare Field designing everyday reports for our doctors and nurses to use on each patient.
In the section of  the report I am trying to improve upon and later on other sections, is the immunizations.
Currently I have a Rectangle and each field is represented within that Rectangle. 30 text boxes.
I currently have it laid out so it shows

```
LABEL - NAME - ADMIN DATE   LABEL - NAME - ADMIN DATE
LABEL - NAME - ADMIN DATE   LABEL - NAME - ADMIN DATE
LABEL - NAME - ADMIN DATE   LABEL - NAME - ADMIN DATE
LABEL - NAME - ADMIN DATE   LABEL - NAME - ADMIN DATE
LABEL - NAME - ADMIN DATE   LABEL - NAME - ADMIN DATE
etc UP TO 30 FIELDS.
```

Now if some of those patients did not get one of these immunizations, it would leave an empty space so it leaves a lot of empty fields and it could look very random.

```
LABEL - NAME - ADMIN DATE   
                            LABEL - NAME - ADMIN DATE   
LABEL - NAME - ADMIN DATE   
                            LABEL - NAME - ADMIN DATE   
LABEL - NAME - ADMIN DATE
```

Just to give you an idea.
I want to use a table instead but I dont have the room to just use up to 30 lines of the page.
So is there a way to limit lets say 10 or 15 rows and then restart the table with remaining rows back at the top? so it would eliminate alot of empty space?
OR show 2 to 3 sets before a carriage return line feed to continue on next line?
This would allow me freedom to add or take away these immunizations without having to totally redo my rectangular box with all the fields shoved inside of it.

I havent posted to one of these sites in a very long time, so whatever I need to add to the post to clarify any questions let me know.
Thanks in Advance!!

I've rewritten my 31 column query to return just 4 columns.

```
PTID - LABEL - NAME - ADMIN DATE.
```

My PTID is the grouping that I have this subrpt being returned into my main report. I can hide that column in the tables returned.

Comment: Presentation of information like this is usually handled via a subreport set to use multiple columns

Comment: We do this for Urine Analysis results on our patient result reports https://mediksoftsaintifik.com/website/images/products/omnilab/EN_PatientUnifiedReport.jpg

Comment: This link might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015098/ssrs-how-to-build-a-simple-multi-column-report

Comment: @BartMcEndree That is Exactly what I am referring to! I am using a subrpt with my  returned columns now, but its returns too many lines. Are you creating that return in the subrpt, or returning it in SQL in those columns?

Comment: Got it, didnt see the link before I commented!! Thanks!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSRS - How to build a simple multi-column report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015098/ssrs-how-to-build-a-simple-multi-column-report)